# Porting AIR app to iOS: do I need an iPad to debug the app?

Tags: ios, flash, air

I'm porting my AIR app to iOS. There're numerous articles/tutorials on how to pack an AIR app. Still I can't catch do I need an iPad to debug my app?

Comment: I don't know about AIR and the iPad emulator specifically, but yes: *sooner or later* you'll *need* the actual hardware that's supposed to run your application. If only to test if the performance is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an iPad to be able to debug on-device.

However, you should be able to debug your app via the ADL iOS emulator as well.
I must say that care should be taken with this debugging method though.

The iOS emulator does not work very well since there are some features that work on the emulator but not on-device. There is already a [feature request](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-31245) in the Adobe jira for this.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! Can you give some manual on how to debug on built in emulator? Do I need a certificate and a provisioning profile for that?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you do need a certificate and provisioning file for debugging on-device. The bad news is that it will cost you 99$ at least :S
Check out http://devgirl.org/2011/06/20/flexair-for-ios-development-process-explained/ for more info on the subject

Comment: ADL comes inbuilt with Flash Builder 4.5. Also, debugging on device is the best option because you can't replicate a touch interface with the mouse

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi, So emulator is built-in AIR SDK? However, I see no specific options in [ADL command line options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fd7.html)

Comment: @Eugeny89 I don't think its in AIR1.5. I've just downloaded FB4.5 and frankly, it is too much of a pain to develop apps for iOS because of all of Adobe's restrictions. The AIR 3 SDK has the built in iOS emulator, but for all the (limited) development I've done, FB4.5 allows you to choose the emulator (Android platform or iOS), so you can do it directly from the IDE.